# Sharepoint Development under different Versions

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, development-environment, sharepoint-2013

i need to get the Jobs of an SharePoint Server. I referenced the necessary assemblies like "Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll" and everything works fine , since i stay on the same version.

I compiled the program against the 2010 Sharepoint assemblies, V14.0
Now i tried to run the program on an 2013 Sharepoint system and the app crashed with an exception that no dll with Version 14.0 could be found..

I read this thread 
[Choose dynamically at runtime which version of a .dll to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488647/choose-dynamically-at-runtime-which-version-of-a-dll-to-use)

and in it the answer is "that it should work" and i have not use dynamic loading ob libraries..

Am i missing something.. I need an working code that runs both on 2010 and 2013 (and of course future versions).

Whats the best setup for this?

I am using the following classes/objects in my app:

- SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.JobDefinitions
- SPHealthReportsList.Local

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried setting "Use specific version" to "No" in property window of referenced assembly in visual studio?

Comment: Sadly this was the default setting.. :( so this is not the problem..

Comment: The guy in the post which you provided is right - SharePoint has binding redirects from old versions. Check web application web config file if it has this redirects. if not you need to add them.